# Format UILabel with image and links

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

How can I add a string with link and image in a UIlabel using swift code.
Below is a sample what I needed:

> Visit to the following link [Terms and conditions](http://www.google.com)  for specific
>   instructions.

I need the Terms and conditions and the bag in red collar and remaining text in grey color. Tapping on red coloured text opens a link.
Anyone please help.

Comment: What have you found/tries so far? It's a common question. Your link leads to a blank Google home page.

Comment: I have added dummy link to present a question as I can't supply the original link

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is, don't do that. A UILabel displays a string. That's what it's made to do. Adding images and links to a label is stretching it well beyond its intended purpose.

You **can** take a generic UIView and add subviews for your text and your image(s). Build your desired contents out of the elements you need.

I would suggest using a UITextView since that supports clickable links. Set it's editable flag to false and turn on link detection.

Answer (score 1):

As per your problem described here. I have found a perfect solution, as per your requirement.

Here is the link to your solution : [Link](http://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/add-image-to-uilabel-with-swift-ios/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and bridge it as it's written in Objective-C

[KILabel](https://github.com/Krelborn/KILabel)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding an attributed text and user interaction to handle link tap. To add image NStextAttachment can be used. Write method to handle tap gesture for label using range.